# Why can't I display array data in React Application?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am quite new to development with React and I am currently trying to get my head around some basic react and redux things. Unfortunately I am experiencing an issue which I cannot fix on my own.

I have written a mock-api which returns players (profileUrl, username, realname, id). I am dispatching an action which successfully gets me one of those players and I can also pass it to my components props using redux' `mapStateToProps`function. But I cannot render any of that data in my `render` function. The react devtools even show me that the single player is getting returned as an array.

**The component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

import * as playerActions from '../../actions/playerActions';

class SinglePlayer extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.loadPlayer(this.props.match.params.playerid);
    }

    /**
     * Render the component.
     */
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.currentPlayer.username }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

/**
 * Defines the state which is exposed to this component.
 * 
 * @param { object } reduxStore The entire redux store. 
 * @param { object } ownProps The properties which belong to the component. 
 */
const mapStateToProps = (reduxStore, ownProps) => {
    return {
        currentPlayer: reduxStore.playerReducer.currentPlayer
    }
}

/**
 * Defines which actions are exposed to this component.
 * 
 * @param { function } dispatch This function is used to dispatch actions.
 */
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(playerActions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SinglePlayer);
```

**React DevTools:**
[Screenshot of React Devtools props](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMLWf.png)

**Redux DevTools:**
[Screenshot of Redux Devtools data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNdw5.png)
As you can tell from the image above, the `currentPlayer` props is inside the `playerReducer` object.

I have also tried looping over the array like so, with no success either. I just get the error-message stating that `.map()` is not a function.

```
this.props.currentPlayer.map(function(player, index) {
    return <p>{ player.username }</p>
)}
```

**Error when using `.map()`:** 
TypeError: this.props.currentPlayer.map is not a function
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Closing tag misses p in the map function?

Comment: That is just a bad copying mistake, it doesn't work even if the tag is closed

Comment: Are you seeing any error on browser console? Also try to `console.log` player before return within map function. See what it prints

Comment: I can't even enter the .map() part, I have updated the post with the errormessage I recieve.

Answer (score 0):

You set your current player by params id at `componentDidMount` . Your render takes place before that currentPlayer is set hence the error. Add a recheck in your render like below.

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { 
                  this.props.currentPlayer && 
                    this.props.currentPlayer.map(function(player, index) {
                      return <p>{ player.username }</>
                    )}
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Or

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                { 
                  this.props.currentPlayer ? 
                    this.props.currentPlayer.map(function(player, index) {
                      return <p>{ player.username }</>
                    )}
                   :
                  null
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Either way it should work. That way `this.props.currentPlayer` will not be rendered or accessed until its available.

**Update**

Udate your `mapStateToProps` to

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        currentPlayer: state.currentPlayer
    }
}
```

I think from your reduxDev tool, currentPlayer is not under any object.

Comment: I have tried both of your methods, but neither of them seem to work for me. I still get the error "this.props.currentPlayer.map is not a function".

Comment: I have tested your update and provided a new screenshot of the data structure inside of the redux devtools. The first screenshot is only from the react-devtools. But it is indeed inside of the playerReducer object.

Answer (score 0):

in first render this.props.currentPlayer is empty!

set empty array "currentPlayer" in state and insert insert this.props.currentPlayer in this.state.currentPlayer and render from state

Comment: I have implemented your answer and it actually worked. Thanks for that. You also made me read more into the react update lifecycle and that is why I finally found my problem myself! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue myself now. The posts here kinda inspired me to try some new things. It was my mock-api which returned the data in a strange and unexpected (at least for me it was unexpected) way.

**The dataset:**

```
const players = [
    {
        profileUrl: 'https://profile.url',
        username: 'player1',
        realname: 'Max Muster',
        steamId: 'player1'
    },
    {
        profileUrl: 'https://profile.url',
        username: 'player2',
        realname: 'Max Mustermann',
        steamId: 'player2'
    },
    {
        profileUrl: 'https://profile.url',
        username: 'player3',
        realname: 'Maxime Musterfrau',
        steamId: 'player3'
    },
];
```

**The filtermethod used:**

```
var player = players.filter(function(el) {
    return el.steamId === 'player1';
});
```

If you assume an array of multiple players like above, the shown filtermethod extracts the correct object but still keeps it wrapped in an array. That was producing the mistake...

Thanks a lot for the help guys!